# Neumann Laplacian

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a Laplace equation on $\Omega$ and some P which solves the Neumann problem. How would I show that adding a constant to P also solves the Neumann problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything is linear, so: $\Delta(P+c) = \Delta P + \Delta c = \Delta P$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial n}(P + c) = \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial n} + \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial n} = \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial n}$.

Comment: What about for Dirichlet?

Comment: If you're referring to Dirichlet boundary conditions: what is the boundary value of $P+c$?